# Redshift loading CSV with commas in a text field

Tags: csv, amazon-redshift

I've been trying to load a csv file with the following row in it:

`91451960_NE,-1,171717198,50075943,"MARTIN LUTHER KING, JR WAY",1,NE`

Note the comma in the name. I've tried all permutations of REMOVEQUOTES, DELIMITER ',', etc... and none of them work.

I have other rows with quotes in the middle of the name, so the ESCAPE option has to be there as well.

According to other posts,
`DELIMITER ',' ESCAPE REMOVEQUOTES IGNOREHEADER 1;`
should work but does not. Redshift gives a "Delimiter not found" error.

Is the ESCAPE causing issues and do I have to escape the comma?

Comment: Could you please Edit your question and provide some rows of sample input, the COPY command you used and the error message you are receiving? This way, we can try to reproduce the situation.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried loading your data using CSV as data format parameter and this worked for me. Please keep in mind that CSV cannot be used with FIXEDWIDTH, REMOVEQUOTES, or ESCAPE.

```
create TEMP table awscptest (a varchar(40),b int,c bigint,d bigint,e varchar(40),f int,g varchar(10));

copy awscptest from 's3://sds-dev-db-replica/test.txt'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::<accounID>:<IAM_role>'
delimiter as ',' EMPTYASNULL CSV NULL AS '\0';
```

References: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-loading-run-copy.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#load-from-csv

Answer (score 1):

This is a commonly recurring question.  If you are actually using the CSV format for you files (not just some ad hoc text file that uses commas) then you need to enclose the field in double quotes.  If you have commas and quotes then you need to enclose the field in double quotes and escape the double quotes in the field data.

There is a definition for the CSV files format - rfc 4180.  All text characters can be represented correctly in CSV if you follow the format.

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt

Use the CSV option to the Redshift COPY command, not just TEXT with a Delimiter of ','.  Redshift will also follow the official file format if you tell it that the files is CSV

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have comma (,) in name field. Clean the data by removing that comma before loading to redshift.

```
df = (df.withColumn('name', F.regexp_replace(F.col('name'), ',', ' ')))
```

Store the new dataframe in s3 and then use the below copy command to load to redshift

```
COPY 'table_name'
FROM 's3 path'
IAM_ROLE 'iam role'
DELIMITER ','
ESCAPE
IGNOREHEADER 1
MAXERROR AS 5
COMPUPDATE FALSE
ACCEPTINVCHARS
ACCEPTANYDATE
FILLRECORD
EMPTYASNULL
BLANKSASNULL
NULL AS 'null';
END;
```